# RAW files in XSI / 450D full auto mode

Tags: raw, canon-450d

Is there a way to get Auto mode to record RAW files on the 450D?

It's for when I hand over the camera to less experience people, it's easiest for them to just use Auto.

I can use 'P' mode as a fallback, but then they still have to choose to popup the flash.

Note: I think the 400D allows this, as it only has one setting for RAW / JPEG, etc. Whereas the 450D has one setting for the manual modes, and one setting for the auto/preset modes, and the latter only offers you a choice of different JPEG sizes.

Comment: You could try aperture priority mode with the ISO and other settings on auto? Set the aperture large to get the light in and the camera should be able to take care of the rest for unexperienced people. My 2c.

Comment: The problem I've found with putting it on Aperture Priority is that the shutter speed will go really low if it's dark and the inexperience people won't know that that's a slow speed and you'll get motion blur - with 'P' and the flash, it will never go below 1/60th.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I know of, I tend to use Program (P) for that exact reason.  As far as choosing to use flash, I actually prefer that situation, since in most situations, on board flash isn't all that helpful, and in some it actually causes problems.

Comment: This really surprised me, I would have figured, at least, that you would be able to do RAW+JPEG.

Comment: Yeah, I don't quite understand the reasoning on that one, but it is also fairly easy to adapt to. Honestly, anyone who is using full auto instead of program probably isn't going to realize most of the gains of shooting raw anyway...

Comment: 'P' with the 430EX on worked reasonably well last time i handed off the camera to others.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there is not a way to use RAW as "Green Box" is fully automatic, the camera does everything.

As noted program Auto Exposure gives you slightly more control.

I've found that if the lighting isn't complicated, the camera does a decent job. Add to that with newer bodies, the incamera calculations have gotten better in successive generations, so green-box is not nearly as limiting for newbies.

One advantage to the images being jpeg, is that since I shoot raw exclusively, and don't swap memory cards until they are full, it makes it super easy to filter out images that were taken by other people.